# Redirecting to /users/username instead of /username

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I wanted to redirect users when they sign in to `/username`. When I use the `redirect_to user`, It, for some reason, redirects to `/users/username`. Example. Instead of going to `site.com/charles`, it goes to `site.com/users/charles`.

I overwrote the `to_param` like this in my `user.rb` file:

```
def to_param
  username
end
```

I have a vanity URL linking to the user.

`match './:username', to: 'users#show',       via: 'get'`

My `sessions_controller.rb` looks like this:

```
def login
    user = User.find_by(username: params[:session][:username])
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      # Sign the user in and redirect to the user's show page.
      sign_in user
      redirect_to user
    else
      flash[:error] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

My signin method is as per Hartl's example, which is where I'm doing this tutorial. I just can't figure out why it's redirecting this way and how I can get to to just redirect to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In routes:

```
get "/:username",
  to: "users#show",
  as: "username"
```

Then you can do

```
redirect_to username_path(user)
```